# generating html dynamically in grails

Tags: grails

I have the following piece of HTML in my `viewer.gsp` page:

```
<div id="bookmarks" style="height:150px;width:250px; padding-left: 100px;margin-top: -54px;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:scroll;">
    <p><a onclick="seek('00:03:00');">00:03:00</a></p>
    <p><a onclick="seek('00:10:45');">00:10:45</a></p>
    <p><a onclick="seek('00:25:30');">00:25:30</a></p>
    <p><a onclick="seek('00:45:31');">00:45:31</a></p>
    <p><a onclick="seek('01:01:01');">01:01:01</a></p>
    <p><a onclick="seek('01:11:11');">01:11:11</a></p>
    <p>${params['bookmarks']}</p>
</div>
```

`params['bookmarks']` contains a sequence of time strings, like `00:04:00`. I would like to be able to print them out as shown above, so it would like something like:

```
foreach(bookmark in bookmarks){
   print "<p><a onclick='seek($bookmark);'>$bookmark</a></p>";
}
```

I suppose `grails` may have some built in functionality that would yield me that.
Could someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you're probably looking for the g:each tag: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/each.html

```
<g:each in="${bookmarks}" var="bookmark">
    <p><a onclick='seek(${bookmark});'>${bookmark}</a></p>
</g:each>
```